# Python GUI for csv transform

Tags: python, csv, user-interface

I have a python script that transforms one (or several) csv files into a different csv file. Rather than running the script from command prompt, I need a GUI that can select multiple files and run the script against them and save the final file to a folder of my choice. Any suggestions? I'm new to GUI design. Thanks!

Comment: http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/

Answer (score 1):

TkInter should do the job, and it has a Select File method:

http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog